# Moving IP masquerade configuration from Debian 10 to 11

Tags: iptables, dnsmasq

Am in the process of moving form Debian 10 to 11 and I'm setting up by network.
The box masquerades the local wired network to the wireless connection to the internet.

The machine is connected to the Internet and can resolve domain names and ping.

It's runnning `dnsmasq` and hosts on the local network are getting configured correctly via DHCP and can resolve domain names.

However hosts cannot connect to the internet -- e.g., can't ping anything.

Here's my `iptables` script

```
#!/bin/sh

iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Any ideas what to check?
(This works in Debian 10.)

**Update**

The problem is IPv6

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
#auto wlp1s0
allow-hotplug wlp1s0
iface wlp1s0 inet manual
        wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#        up /usr/sbin/wondershaper -a wlan0 -d 9500 -u 15000
#        down /usr/sbin/wondershaper -a wlan0 -c

allow-hotplug RWB
iface RWB inet dhcp
```

and

```
n# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
4: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ec:63:00:00:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2a00:23ee:2648:a0f:2ec:63ff:fe00:2d/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 3256sec preferred_lft 3256sec
    inet6 fe80::2ec:63ff:fe00:2d/64 scope link
```

So: how do I get rid of this IPv6 nonsense and get back to normal?

**Get rid of IP6**

Add to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Comment: if that "works in Debian 10", then there's no reason it shouldn't in Debian 11.

Comment: It's better to share/check `iptables-save` in case anything other than your script has interfered. Also check `nft list ruleset`. Also make sure the interface name hasn't changed. You should also see if DNS resolution *alone* on the "client" hosts work, before maybe `tcpdump` on this "router" host to see if it gives you any hint.

Comment: It's to do with IPv6.
The `wsp1s0` is only getting an IP 6 address and not a normal IP 4 address.

Comment: Your configuration for `wlp1s0` only tells the system to start `wpa_supplicant` for it; because of `iface wlp1s0 inet manual`, the DHCP client will not be automatically started for it unless you have added it to the configuration of wpa_supplicant somehow. Having IPv6 address(es) does not stop the network interface from also having an IPv4 address, but a missing DHCP client invocation surely would.

Comment: I think the `inet RWB` thing (`RWB` is the access point name) is what runs the DHDC client on `wsp1s0`. Under Debian 10 it was getting a normal IP address and everything was good. Now it's only getting an IP6 address and it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like you've put your answer into the question. An answer belongs as an answer (below), which you can then accept if a better suggestion doesn't come along

Comment: `RWB` doesn't appear in your interfaces list. So if you don't know exactly what it is and don't explain it to us, we can't guess. Then if you expect to do NAT using `wsp1s0`, `wsp1s0` requires an IPv4 address. You can completely forget about IPv6 until you know what changed between before and now.